# python - breaking out of nested conditional to top of original loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm having issues with this part of my code:

```
if(input not in status_list):
    print("Invalid Entry, try again.")
    break
```

The break exits the whole program, I just want to go back to the beginning of the program (to *while(1):)* 
 I've tried pass, continue, return can't think of anything else.. can anyone help??
Thanks :)
**Also** it's reading this variable income as a string still..: `income = int(input("Enter taxable income: "))` The error message I get is "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

```
import subprocess
status_list = ["s","mj","ms","h"]


while(1):
    print ("\nCompute income tax: \n")
    print ("Status' are formatted as: ")
    print ("s = single \n mj = married and filing jointly \n ms = married and filing seperately \n h = head of household \n q = quit\n")
    input = input("Enter status: ")
    if(input == 'q'):
        print("Quitting program.")
        break
    if(input not in status_list):
        print("Invalid Entry, try again.")
        break 

    income = int(input("Enter taxable income: "))
    income.replace("$","")
    income.replace(",","")

    #passing input to perl files
    if(input == 's'):
        subprocess.call("single.pl")
    elif(input == 'mj'):
        subprocess.call("mj.pl", income)
    elif(input == 'ms'):
        subprocess.call("ms.pl", income)
    else:
        subprocess.call("head.pl", income)
```

Comment: Stylistically, you should avoid brackets around the conditions of your `if`s and `while`s (i.e. `while 1:` instead of `while(1):`, `if input == 's':` instead of `if(input == 's'):`...)

Comment: `continue` should do exactly what you want here.

Comment: It's hard to to understand how `continue` failed to work

Comment: When I use continue that I get an error saying `input = input("Enter status:")` TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = input("Enter status: ")
```

You rebind the name `input` from the `input` function to its result, which is a string.  So the next time you call it, after `continue` does its work, `input` doesn't name a function any more, it's just a string, and you can't call a string, hence

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Use `continue`, and change your variable name so as not to clobber the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't continue, it's that you have an unresolved error further down in your code. Continue is doing exactly what it's supposed to (i.e. you want `continue` in that conditional).

You're renaming `input` as a string, so the name no longer points to the builtin `input` function in your code. This is why you don't use reserved keywords as variable names. Call your variable something other than "input" and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Continue is working correctly. The problem with your script is that you're trying to call replace() on an int:

```
income = int(input("Enter taxable income: "))
# income is an int, not a string, so the following fails
income.replace("$","")
```

You can do something like this instead:

```
income = int(input("Enter taxable income: ").replace("$", "").replace(",", ""))
```